# How Solve equation having Matrix parameters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, parameters, equation

I want to solve the following equation for X. All parameters in my equation are matrices:

```
( [A]' * [X] )+( [X] * [A] ) = -I

I =

     0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0
     0         0    6.7955   -2.8529
     0         0   -2.8529    3.9426
```

and

```
[A] =

 -0.0038   -0.0011   -0.0012   -0.0012
 -0.0011   -0.0049   -0.0012   -0.0023
  1.0000       0         0        0
     0      1.0000       0        0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`sylvester`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sylvester.html):

```
>> sylvester(A', A, -I)

ans =

   1.0e+06 *

    2.2772   -1.4202    0.0071   -0.0045
   -1.4202    0.9749   -0.0043    0.0032
    0.0071   -0.0043    0.0011   -0.0005
   -0.0045    0.0032   -0.0005    0.0005
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but when I use solution I faced this ...
>> sylvester(A', A, -I0)
Undefined function 'sylvester' for input arguments of type 'doubl

Comment: @AriaAfshari the MATLAB documentation states `Introduced in R2014a`, so you are probably running a too old version which does not have this function